# How to read filenames in a text file in C++

Tags: c++

I know you can use fstream to read a textfile. However if my textfile has a list of names of other files, How do I open and read those?
[image: textfile example]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string line;
fstream myfile("mytextfile.txt");

 if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;

}
```

This just opens the stated file. How do I open and read "citylocation.txt" and "cloudcover.txt".

Comment: You need to parse each line, and recognize if its a "range" or a filename. If it's a filename, call a function to handle handle that specific file, passing the filename.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't `.close()` the files. They will automatically close when they go out of scope.

Comment: would using something like regex to find for lines with .txt be the best way?

Comment: You can use `ends_with` (if you have C++20) to check if a string has a suffix `.txt`. Otherwise, you can extract 4 bytes at the end and compare them with `".txt"`. Or, indeed, use `regex`. But your file format should tell exactly where file names appear, so you shouldn't need to guess whether a string is a filename or not.

Comment: How are you supposed to know the difference between `citylocation.txt` and `cloudcover.txt` in your program? Does the file with city locations always come before the file with cloud coverage inside this file? If not, what if the file contains `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`? Which one contains city locations? Are you supposed to parse the supposed comments above the filenames too?

Comment: for now im just trying to read filename stored in a textfile. But I suppose the order is fixed. I am trying a past year assignment from my uni as practice to learn. Here is the link if you want to check it out. https://www.studocu.com/en-au/document/university-of-wollongong/advanced-programming/csci251-cpp-assignment-1/23252998

Answer (score 1):

If your file `mytextfile.txt` contains two names of other files

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Use the following code:

```
int main()
{
    string filename1;
    string filename2;
    ifstream myfile("mytextfile.txt");
    getline(myfile, filename1);
    getline(myfile, filename2);

    string line;
    ifstream file1(filename1);
    ifstream file2(filename2);
    while (getline(file1, line)) // read and print first file
        cout << line << '\n';
    while (getline(file2, line)) // read and print second file
        cout << line << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

If you have several (unknown number) of file names in your txt file, use a loop (marked with "read a file name" in the code below):

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile("mytextfile.txt");
    string filename;

    while (getline(myfile, filename)) // read a file name
    {
        ifstream file(filename); // open the file
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line)) // read the file
            cout << line << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If any error occurs (e.g. file is not found), it's silently ignored - I omitted error handling for brevity.

Comment: This answer is technically totally wrong. How shall it extract the file names from the source file in the question? It does not even make an attempt to do so. And upvoted? Very strange . Please edit or delete your answer

Comment: I just tried it and it works! (i used the second method) From my understanding the first loop read all the contents of the file into "filename" and tries to open it in the second loop. If the string is .txt file which exists, it will proceed to the second loop and cout the values

Comment: It works in 99.9% of cases, because other data in your file don't look like filenames. If your file contains data like `99` and you happen to have a file with name `99`, it will read that file, potentially causing chaos. You need proper parsing for your file format; this answer is only good to show what to do when your parser finds a filename.